# Are Lockheed Martin nuclear fusion claims realistic?

Tags: nuclear-physics, plasma-physics, fusion, nuclear-engineering

Lockheed Martin reported breakthroughs on nuclear fusion technology for energy. Are these claims scientifically realistic?

The claims have been reported in the media: http://www.nbcnews.com/science/science-news/how-lockheed-martins-power-play-could-boost-fervor-over-fusion-n227366

Comment: $\uparrow$ reported where?

Comment: Related post: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141529/

Comment: see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_mirror

Comment: Lubos Motl blogged about it: http://motls.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/lockheed-martin-promises-fusion-plants.html

See a video by the company here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UlYClniDFkM

I must say that due to the history of too optimistic outlooks concerning fusion I am sceptical.

Comment: Lockheed Martin Compact Fusion: http://www.lockheedmartin.com/us/products/compact-fusion.html http://www.bizjournals.com/sanfrancisco/prnewswire/press_releases/California/2014/10/15/DA37396

Comment: It just shows that even Lockheed occasionally hires the wrong people and doesn't give them the supervision they require to not break their toys. Having said that, even the mainstream fusion crowd has made these kinds of announcements since, at least, the 1950s... and they are still a decade away from building a borderline working Tokamak. We are all humans, even the best scientists (and the Lockheed guy is not even among "the best" scientists). :-)

Comment: Tokamaks are engineering nightmares that will never form the basis of commercial power generators

Comment: @DirkBruere surely an engineer's nightmare is actually an engineer's dream.. you wouldn't want it to be easy - it be boring :)

Comment: Some articles suggest that the claimed breakthrough has something to do with the magnetic fields "naturally" compensating for changing motions in the plasma through feedback effects--for example, [this one](http://www.wired.com/2014/10/lockheed-martin-fusion/) says *'McGuire designed a magnetic container that shifts the strength of its magnetic field to match those plasma ripples. “If we have a perturbation or a ripple that sends it closer to the wall, the magnetic field gets stronger and stronger, so it has the right kind of feedback to keep it stable,” McGuire says.'*

Comment: So I wonder if there could be a connection or analogy between what they're suggesting and [diamagnetically stabilized levitation](http://www.physics.ucla.edu/marty/diamag/ajp601.pdf), which works especially well with superconductors. Magnetic levitation is ordinarily difficult because of Earnshaw's theorem which rules out stable levitating configurations with static fields, and artificially adjusting the fields with an electromagnet to keep magnets from flipping over is tricky, but diamagnets "naturally" adjust currents to compensate for motions of the levitated magnet.

Comment: @hypnosifl What you read sounds like stabilization of MHD modes, which are an issue for theta-pinch configurations.  This has been known for some time and techniques have been developed to stabilize it.  The question in my mind has to do with turbulent transport and its effects on confinement.  This is a well known issue that the best of minds are struggling with in the field.  I'd be surprised to hear that the problem has been solved without actually having built the device, as theoretical predictions fall quite a bit short of what experimentalists are measuring.

Comment: @user3814483 - Did the existing techniques to stabilize MHD modes already involve natural feedback effects where the magnetic field automatically becomes stronger to push back ripples, or did they require artificially adjusting the fields? If existing methods already involved natural feedback, it's odd that McGuire presents this as an innovation, unless the idea is just that they've improved the technique in some way.

Comment: @Hypnosifl The ideas aren't new; people talk about "good" and "bad" B curvature in the context of instabilities.  The application may be novel (e.g., novel geometry that is stable). I haven't seen a single paper so it's difficult to say anything about what has actually been done.  Also think it's strange that, based on my observations, they have not engaged the broader plasma/fusion community for the last several years, and are now looking to partner up.  This isn't about funding, as Lockheed probably has more of that than DOE can dedicate to a side project.

Comment: @Dave - The best "long shot" is probably dense plasma focus fusion. It is simple (compared to all the rest) and will either work, or just totally fail. All the others need constant $billion tweaks to keep the optimism level high.

Comment: [This article from Science/AAAS](http://news.sciencemag.org/physics/2014/10/updated-are-old-secrets-behind-lockheeds-new-fusion-machine) has some informed speculation about what their approach might consist of, mentioning that it probably uses a "cusp geometry" approach like the "picket fence", and also mentioning that recent patents filed by the lead researcher indicate it's "some sort of cusp geometry device but more complicated than a picket fence. It also appears to have a structure known as a magnetic mirror at either end."