# Why did the Lockheed Martin compact fusion reactor failed?

Tags: nuclear-physics, plasma-physics, fusion, nuclear-engineering

What made the compact fusion reactor to not be compact. What assumptions did lokheed made in its simulation that showed that it could work. Can we do anything that could make it work or it is completely impossible.

Comment: This has been discussed a few times: [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141679/) or [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141529/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the High beta fusion reactor work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141529/)